# Adding background in navigation bar associated with the main content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I associate the background image to my navigation bar? I tried my best to associate it but I failed. Do you have any tutorials or tips how can I make it?

> Here's my index

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav><!--End of navbar-->

    <!-- start of picture div-->
    <div id="bgp">

              <h1 id="top-header">

              </h1>  

    </div>
```

> Here's my CSS:

```
#bgp
{
background-image: url("images/city.png");
opacity: 0.8;
width: 100%;
height: 100rem;
background-size: 100%,500%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample codes?

Comment: Do you want a single page application where, depending on selected menu point different content is shown or what ?

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. There you go

Comment: @noa-dev i want my navbar background is the same to my bgp image

Comment: You want to use the same background image for your NAV so that content + nav have the same image? If thats the case dont asign your background image to the div , instead asign it to tbe body element

Comment: @noa-dev sir i dont want to make that image as my main background. i just want to combine the background of my navbar and my div

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of what you want and provide a FIDDLE ? then ill take a look on how to help you :)

Comment: @noa-dev this is the example that i was trying to copy [link]http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/

Comment: @user2714693 Are you using twitter-bootstrap?

Comment: @user2714693 Based on the link you provided, it is a **github** repository so you will be able to view the source code by yourself. Here's the link: https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-creative

Answer (score 0):

Alright here you go : https://jsfiddle.net/d7uamo66/

Basically the header has NO image but is transparent.
`If` you scroll down the header transparency changes to white.